# BoDi.ObjectContainerException: Interface cannot be resolved: TechTalk.SpecFlow.UnitTestProvider.IUnitTestRuntimeProvider('nunit')

Tags: mstest, specflow, vstest

I have a test project in VS 2019 with Specflow.
I updated to Specflow 3.4.3.
I want to use MsTest as test provider, therefore I have installed the Specflow.MsTest nuget package.
Building the project works, but when I try to execute one of the tests in the project with vstestconsole via the command line by using the built .dll on one of my test machines, I am getting the following error:

```
MSTestAssemblyHooks.AssemblyInitialize threw exception. BoDi.ObjectContainerException: BoDi.ObjectContainerException: Interface cannot be resolved: TechTalk.SpecFlow.UnitTestProvider.IUnitTestRuntimeProvider('nunit'). Aborting test execution.
  Stack Trace:
      at BoDi.ObjectContainer.TypeRegistration.Resolve(ObjectContainer container, RegistrationKey keyToResolve, ResolutionList resolutionPath)
   at BoDi.ObjectContainer.ResolveObject(RegistrationKey keyToResolve, ResolutionList resolutionPath)
   at BoDi.ObjectContainer.Resolve(Type typeToResolve, ResolutionList resolutionPath, String name)
   at BoDi.ObjectContainer.Resolve[T](String name)
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.ContainerBuilder.CreateGlobalContainer(Assembly testAssembly, IRuntimeConfigurationProvider configurationProvider)
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.TestRunnerManager.CreateTestRunnerManager(Assembly testAssembly, IContainerBuilder containerBuilder)
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.TestRunnerManager.GetTestRunnerManager(Assembly testAssembly, IContainerBuilder containerBuilder, Boolean createIfMissing)
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.TestRunnerManager.OnTestRunStart(Assembly testAssembly, IContainerBuilder containerBuilder)
```

Does anybody know how to resolve that issue?

Comment: Are you coping the files somewhere out of the output directory? There should be a TechTalk.SpecFlow.MsTest.SpecFlowPlugin.dll in the same folder as your test assembly.

Comment: Yes, it is in the same folder

Comment: Strange. Please open an issue on https://github.com/SpecFlowOSS/SpecFlow. I am special interested in your command line command to run the tests.
Btw, does it work in Visual Studio?

Comment: I cannot test it in Visual Studio as on the system where VS is installed, the software that is tested is not installed there.
My command line command is: vstest.console.exe MyTestDll.dll /TestCaseFilter:"Name=MyTestName"

Comment: Issue on github created: https://github.com/SpecFlowOSS/SpecFlow/issues/2120

Comment: Which NuGet packages to you have installed in your test project?

Comment: SpecFlow.3.4.3, SpecFlow.MsTest.3.4.3, SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.3.4.3, MSTest.TestFramework.1.3.2 and with Specflow package their come some dependent packages that are also installed

Comment: got the same problem, but only some of my colleagues

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the NuGet packages you have installed. It is too easy to miss this information in comments. Besides, if you have MS Test packages installed, and it is complaining about NUnit, then something is misconfigured.